# update a database from two different user at a time

Tags: java, database

I am just trying to make a project in which there might be many employee and doctors may access. it will contain a database and interface and i want to do it in java.But now i am facing a problem -i am not sure how to make the database be able to update at a time ,i mean when an employee update the database the other can access the updated database.i have previously use database in the local host where user is one.

Comment: Which database - most allow multiple users to access at the same time - what you need to read up on is transactions

Comment: I am sorry but i don't understand. Can you give me a sample source code?i have gone through the transaction material but don't find any necessary term.

Comment: What transaction material have you gone through?

Comment: I connect my java with database by this-connect = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?","",""); here test is db name. If i connect to a host instead of localhost then may i be able to access the database from different user? Here i am telling about to connect to a server host.

Answer (score -1):

You can use synchronized blocks or monitorfunctions with semaphors in Java.
Put this around the method calling the database and you can control number of simultaneous access to the database.

Comment: This sounds like overkill. A better idea would be to use database transactions.

Comment: and if fails if two java programs hit the same db